# regular expression for (a<1) or (b=2) and (c>3)

Tags: regex

My expression is `(a<1) or (b=2) and (c>3)`

I want to extract variable names (`a`, `b`, `c`) and store them in an array called `var[]`.

Similarly values(`1`, `2`, `3`)and operators (`or`, `and`) . Should I use regular expression, if not what it would be?

Answer (score 1):

No, you shouldn't. This is much more of a hierarchical parser problem.

What you should do is a) find something that gives you a abstract parsing tree for exactly what you need, or b) design the above using one of the many parser builders out there -- try reading up on flex or bison. Maybe you'd want to have a look at antlr, too.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what language you are using and you haven't given very many matches. A basic RegEx would be:

```
(?<=\()[^)>=<]*
```

Which will get the characters after the (

```
(?<=\()[A-Za-z]*
```

will get the letters after the (

---

Perhaps:

```
(?<=\()(.*?)(?:[=><])([^)\n])
```

Might work better which would capture both parts